# How to grab a return value from a sub-method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am required to take all user input from within a void method (though it's important to note that the original verbiage says the method must not have a return value), and have all output be relegated to a separate method.

Now, I have all that set up and it's passing the relevant array to the sub method just fine (because I call the sub method from within the void method). But, I need the main to actually do the rest of the calling using the value from that sub method in other methods.

An in depth explanation and teaching would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you will need to break down several more methods to capture the user input from within the void method. You can use `this.variable = variable` to assign the user input (passed through an argument) to save the user input to the object variable. Then write a `getVariable()` method to get the state of that variable from the object. Without showing an example of the code, this question is very vague and hard to answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have luxury to change the signature of the methods (keeping the return type as void), you can pass another data structure to the methods. That way, you can get the user inputs inside GetUserInput(customDataStruct) method, pass it to SubMethod(customDataStruct) method. SubMethod() will modify the customDataStruct content, which will be available directly in main(), if main() invokes GetuserInput().

Second option, as @Fiddle suggested, is to use a global variable and let the methods manipulate it. This global variable shall be accessible from main().

Comment: There are no global variables in Java. Do you mean member variables?

Comment: @Rober, By 'global', i was referring to the variable that is available at application level, instead of class members. e.g. declare variable in the class that hosts main() method and have that variable pass to wherever needed etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had it flipped. By letting the void method be the sub method and *actually learning to pass by reference* (enjoy my head smacking) I was able to use the method with the return to bring the value back to main.

Comment: Please edit (or delete) your question instead of posting non-answers like this.